# Where is scaffold in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, ide, rubymine

I'm trying RubyMine, and watching this tutorial https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/documentation/ . The author uses there **project->new->scaffold** but i could not find scaffold there. What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever searching for something in RubyMine, a highliy recommented thing is "Search"->"Find Action" (Cmd-Shift-A).

Just type "scaffold" in the search field and it shows the relevant IDE actions.

Answer (score 7):

Click on File -> New -> Run Rails Generator...

type scaffold and press enter

in the next dialog you can enter the scaffold parameters

Answer (score 1):

With RubyMine, I often find it easier to use the terminal for Rails commands like generating scaffolds and migrations and use the RubyMine interface for watching what's happening in the server console, raking the database or routes, etc.  It's sort of the best of both worlds.  Good luck.